# XMLHTTP Get request's responseText is blank even though API does return data (MS Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, get, xmlhttprequest

I am using below code to do a GET request to my Google Sheets' apps script project's web app URL -

```
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim responseData() As String

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?data=" & "id" & " | " & "date1" & "&mode=update"
'above URL works in browser
Debug.Print strUrl
blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .Send
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Debug.Print .responseText 'empty
    strResponse = .responseText 'empty
    Debug.Print strResponse 'empty
End With

responseData = Split(strResponse, " | ")
Debug.Print UBound(responseData) - LBound(responseData) + 1 'prints 0
```

When I open the printed URL in my browser, I see that the data is being returned -

[image]

Which means my google apps script web app is working, but the VBA code is not - what could be wrong? Why is VBA code not fetching the returned data from the URL? My end goal is just to get the string returned, split it by `" | "` character and get the values in the `responseData` varible.

What should I do? Please guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried sending the request synchronously? I've a suspicion that readyState is always 4 on an asynchronous call. Have you checked if the page load dynamically? Perhaps your date hasn't loaded when the responseText is already available?

Comment: @Ambie thanks for replying... can you please elaborate on checking if page loads dynamically? how do I check that? also about the date, the date does load before the URL preparation, as I see it in immediate window when I debug print the `strURL`.

Comment: For testing, put a time delay of say 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but I recently tried to pull back some text from websites using various code I found on the internet and most of them didn't seem to work. Whether this is a vagary of Office 365 or I just couldn't get them to work I don't know, but finally I ended up using XMLHTTP60 calls to return the data I wanted which was pulling back SMILES/smiles from CAS numbers.

The code I use and which you should be able to adapt is below:

```
Public Function getCactusSMILES(ByVal CAS As String) As String
    ' Requires References: Microsoft XML, v6.0; Microsoft HTML Object Library
    
    Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60: Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
    myRequest.Open "GET", "https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + CAS + "/smiles", False
    myRequest.Send
    
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = myRequest.ResponseText
    If Not html Is Nothing Then
        Dim text As String: text = Trim(html.body.innerText)
        If text <> "Page not found (404)" Then getCactusSMILES = text
    End If
    Set myRequest = Nothing
    DoEvents

End Function
```

> OR

```
Public Function getPubChemSMILES(ByVal CAS As String) As String
    ' Requires References: Microsoft XML, v6.0; Microsoft HTML Object Library
    
    Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60: Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
    myRequest.Open "GET", "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/xref/rn/" + CAS + "/property/isomericsmiles/txt", False
    myRequest.Send
    
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = myRequest.ResponseText
    If Not html Is Nothing Then
        Dim text As String: text = Trim(html.body.innerText)
        If Not InStr(text, "PUGREST.NotFound") > 0 Then getPubChemSMILES = Split(text, " ")(0)
    End If
    Set myRequest = Nothing
    DoEvents

End Function
```